# Vector Plus a Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, conjugate-gradient

I am working my way through [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Equake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf) intro on conjugate gradient and I've come to a place I could use some help with understanding.

In Section 7.3 on Optimality of the Error Term, an example is given where we have two search directions $d_0$ and $d_1$ which are vectors that form subspace $D_2 = \text{Span}(d_0, d_1)$. Since we have only two vectors that means $D_2$ forms a plane which is reflected in Figure 26.

Next, we have some initial error vector $e_0$ which is shown as a vector that starts at $(0,0)$ which lies above $D_2$ and ends at a point in $D_2$ (also in Figure 26).

The author then says the new error vector $e_i$ is chosen from $e_0 + D_2$. This is where I am confused. What is a vector plus a subspace? Is this just $\text{Span}(e_0, d_0, d_1)$? Does it mean that the space of vectors from which we can choose is now defined by any vector lying in $D_2$ as well as any vector starting at $(0,0)$ and ending in $D_2$?

Comment: I guess $e_0 + D_2 = \{e_0 + v \;|\; v \in D_2\}$.

Comment: It is an example of a coset, by the way.

Comment: @Abezhiko thanks now I understand.

Comment: @SeanRoberson never heard of that before